# Facebook authentication using c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, winforms

I've been searching for a way to make a facebook authentication class in C#. All I can find is javascript. It'd be completely fine, but I want to make a C# class out of it. One I can use in multiple platforms. I need to be able to authenticate in ASP, desktop (windows forms) and mobile app (xamarin).

Even if it isn't possible with just one generic class I'd be happy if I could do one for each of them so I can have them in my library class and I just need to call it from the UI.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Take a look at the [Facebook SDK for .NET](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I was looking for something a bit simples, as for the code facebook provides in javascript but in c#. Is this the only way?